# UIAlertAction handler late response in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I want to change value of varibale(BOOL) in handler block when user tapp on any button yes or no. But my problem is that handler executed at last when  after other code also executed and value of variable changed after code executed.Here is my code..

```
isValidated = NO;
    self.lblError.hidden = NO;
    // Alert style
    NSLog(@"First log");

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Already have absense registration at same time." message:@"Do you want to save this registration?? " preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *YesAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
        isValidated = YES;
        self.lblError.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"Second log");


    }];
    [alertController addAction:YesAction];

    UIAlertAction *NoAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
        //do something when click button

        isValidated = NO;
        self.lblError.hidden = NO;

    }];
    [alertController addAction:NoAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Third log");
```

required output:

1. First log
2. Second log
3. Third log

But here is output that recieved:

1. First log
2. Third log
3. Second log

Here "Second log" executed after "Third log" but i want that compiler wait for execution of handler block then go forward..
Please help me..

Comment: You should move the rest of the execution to another method and then call it from the action handlers.

Comment: that is how asynchron tasks work, deal with it ;) move all logic depending on the user action to the actual callback

Comment: @ZeMoon thanks for comment .. but its requirement.. any other suggesstions???

Comment: @luk2302 any example or code???

Comment: then change your "requirement"! No code from me. What I am saying does not need no code - you have already a callback block in your action. Everything depening on the user action HAS to be done in there. Move the `NSLog(@"Third log");` and voila. Why did you change your code to include the horrific dispatches? Was that your previous code already?

Comment: General note: DONT change your code to incorporate an answer. If a new reader comes to the question he does not know what your actual code is - the current code is FAAAAAR worse than what you started with, please revert to your original code.

Comment: yes i have already code

Comment: thanks for your note .... :) i have changed back to my original code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you block the main thread, waiting for the alert to be dismissed, you will create a deadlock, as the touch events are processed on the main thread, and you are blocking it.

There are a few different ways to handle delayed execution, and you should choose whichever you think best fits your situation.

**Method 1**

The simplest thing to do is to put whatever code has to run after the user chooses right into the alert action handler.

**Method 2**

Use a dispatch group and a `dispatch_group_notify()` invocation to setup a block that will run as soon as an action is chosen.

*Setup:*

Before creating the alert:

```
dispatch_group_t postAlertGroup = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_enter(postAlertGroup);
```

Inside *both* alert action handlers:

```
dispatch_group_leave();
```

After displaying the alert:

```
dispatch_group_notify(postAlertGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Post alert code goes here
});
```

Comment: Without seeing your modified code, it's impossible to tell what's wrong.  You should be going with Method 1, by the way, unless you understand why you'd prefer Method 2.

Comment: I really don't recommend it.  Why did you choose that method over the much simpler Method 1?

Comment: Show the code you are trying now, and explain what exactly isn't working.  Update your question, so you can format properly.

Comment: The idea is that your 3rd `NSLog()` should be inside the notify block.  That block is only executed when the dispatch group is left (exited).

Comment: thanks man :) for your time  +1,, its working with mixture of both methods 1 and 2 . :)

Comment: @Avi , could the second method be used in a scenario where there are three alert after each other, depending on circumstances, and if all are ok some other method is called?

Comment: Yes, that method works well when there are variable alerts.  You have to be careful to balance the calls to `dispatch_group_enter()` and `dispatch_group_leave()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour.
As the first log is printed before the object is created so it is being logged first, and the third log is printed after the ``alertviewcontroller is shown. Meanwhile the second Log is printed as the ACTION of the `alertviewcontroller`.

So as in runtime, this happens in a very short time, (alert being created and shown), so the time between first and third log is too little, BUT the second log is dependent on Users interaction.
So First and Third log is being printed just when the alert is drawn on screen, thus there is no way you can interact between that time, and log the second by your interaction.

Hope this clears up.

Comment: thanks for your replay but i know the behaviour and i want its solution not reason that why it heapens..